# How do I grant all privileges to current administrator account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, administrator

I bought a new Acer Notebook PC with Microsoft Windows 10 which came with one administrator account and a guest account. While an administrator account is supposed to have all the privileges, mine doesn't.

For example,

If I right click any folder in `C:\` drive (whether in the root or folder within a folder) and point to the `New` option, only option I can see is `New Folder` and no option for Notepad or Word Document.

If I open any text file with notepad, edit it and try to save it, access is denied which means I have to open notepad with elevated privileges first and then manually open the file from the application to be able to edit and save it.

Note that there is only one drive `(C: drive)` which is probably the reason for this high security. I didn't find any option in Control Panel except for removing UAC but that doesn't seem to work for this case. How can I turn off this security feature?

Comment: Take ownership of folders you want access to your administrator's account

Comment: What you describe is exactly how it should behave.  The directory your trying to create a file in is a protected directory this means you must elevate the permissions to create the file.  This behavior cannot be changed in Windows 8+

Comment: Creating files in the root of the C: drive is a bad habit and on a multi user system could leave you open to people side swiping your data or replacing it with malicious executables. There are good reasons to prevent that behaviour. Put your files somewhere else, such as your user profile or desktop.